# How to set significant figures in pyplot annotation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

P-values and D-Values from a K-S test need to be displayed on a pylot histogram.  Thankfully, my p-values are low, but are so low they display as `0.0` when I use `round`.  I also tried `numpy.set_printoptions(precision=3)` to limit my significant digits to the thousands place, but this only changed my output printing to the interpreter, and not to the graph.

```
 ks_D, ks_p = ks_2samp(cntrl, test)

 ks_summ = "K-S D-value = {}\nK-S p-value = {}".format(round(ks_D, 3), round(ks_p, 3))
pyplot.annotate(ks_summ, xy=(0.70, 0.75), xycoords='axes fraction')
```

So how can I display `1.2228387401e-24` (`<class 'numpy.float64'>`) as `1.223e-24` in a graph annotation?

Here is my graph with p-value showing as 0.0:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need modify the line

```
ks_summ = "K-S D-value = {}\nK-S p-value = {}".format(round(ks_D, 3), round(ks_p, 3))
```

to read

```
ks_summ = "K-S D-value = {}\nK-S p-value = {:.3e}".format(round(ks_D, 3), ks_p)
```

The `{:.3e}` format means 3 decimal places with exponential notation. And since the rounding to 3 decimal places in included in this formatting notation, we can drop the code to round `ks_p`.  For example:

```
>>> ks_p = 1.2228387401e-24
>>> '{:.3e}'.format(ks_p)
'1.223e-24'
```

Finally, note that you can apply a string format to `ks_D`, as well.  Something `{:.3f}` may do the trick (i.e. three decimal place rounding).

```
>>> ks_D = 0.38210101
>>> '{:.3f}'.format(ks_D)
'0.382'
```

Comment: That worked well, thanks.  That {:.3e} formatting was totally new to me.